# How to split Matlab string into two with known suffix?

Tags: matlab, parsing

I need to split a string into two components. As an example I have the string:

```
s = 'Hello1_1000_10_1_data'
```

and I want to split it into the two strings

```
str1 = 'Hello1_1000_10_1'
```

and

```
str2 = '_data'
```

the important point is that I can't be too sure of the format of the first string, the only thing that is sure is that the 'suffix' which is to be read into the second string always reads '_data'. What is the best way to do this? I looked up the documentation on strtok and regexp but they do not seem to offer me what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you always know the length of the suffix, you could just use that:

```
s = 'Hello1_1000_10_1_data'
str1 = s(1:end-5)
```

Or otherwise:

```
s = 'Hello1_1000_10_1_data'
suffix = length('_data')
str1 = s(1:end-suffix)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
s = 'Hello1_1000_10_1_data';

str = regexp(s, '(.*)(_data)', 'tokens'){1};
str{1}    %//     Hello1_1000_10_1
str{2}    %//     _data
```

If `_data` occurs several times in the file name, this will still work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use strfind():

```
s = 'Hello1_1000_10_1_data';
suffix = '_data';
i = strfind(s,suffix);
if any(i)
    i = i(end);
    prefix = s(1:i-1);
end
```

Comment: You need to be careful with this, just incase the suffix string occurs more than once - i.e. if "_data" appears in the prefix part as well as at the end. `strfind` will return the index of both occurrences, but `s(1:i-1)` will then return just the part before the first occurrence of "_data".

Comment: @MattSwain you are obviously right, so i updated the version. It now only splits the string at the last time the suffix is found and only splits, if it is found at all. But since the suffix should appear always (as stated in the problem description), your solution seems to be the best.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `strsplit()` as follow:

```
s = 'Hello1_1000_10_1_data';
suffix = '_data';
str = strsplit(s,suffix);
str1 = str{1}
```

In addition, you can use `strsplit()` with multiple delimiters.

Comment: You need to be careful with this, just in case the suffix string occurs more than once - i.e. if "_data" appears in the prefix part as well as at the end. `strsplit` will then return multiple components, and `str{1}` won't be all the text before the final "_data".